# Visual Studio install project launch condition to check for StyleCop

Tags: windows-installer, stylecop

I have created a set of default project templates and development framework libraries. I currently have 2 separate installers bunt now want to combine the into a single installer and also ensure that StyleCop is installed as a prerequisite.

If StyleCop hasn't been installed, I want it to be downloaded and installed.

Once I've confirmed StyleCop has been installed I want to overwrite the global style rules to conform with our coding standards.

Is this going to be possible without writing a custom installer?

Comment: It depends on the setup authoring tool you are using. Some have the options that allow you to easily create the package without any scripting, while others require some time dedicated for creating the package, like Wix for example. Do you have some restraints on the development tools? Or your looking for one that can allow you to build the package as easy as possible?

Comment: Since posting, I've been looking t the setup projects that come with visual studio. I can use the registry to identify is StyleCop has been installed. I'm now working my way though determining the file path to the global settings file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out to be quite simple once I'd tracked down the relevant How To's on MSDN.

The first step is to add a launch condition search on the target machine. You can see how this is done [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4awx1f1d.aspx)

The screen shot below shows the registry key and value to search for.
[image: StyleCop registry search properties]

The launch condition properties should look like this...
[image: launch condition properties]

The File system folder should then be configured as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0z89y5d.aspx).
The screen shot below shows the folder properties.

[image: file system folder properties]
**NOTE: I use the PID value from the registry to ensure I'm overwriting the correct settings file.**